# onClick function in React not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

My simple react code is:

main.js:

```
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');

var Main = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
    return(
        <div>

            <a onClick={alert("hello world")} >hello</a>

    </div>

        )

    }
});
```

in console there were an error :

> TypeError: listener must be a function

**ERROR:**

> while running this code, I am getting that alert function instead of
>   that this should be on click function.

**Note**: I am using *flux* structure but there were no data populating in given file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your alert code in an anonymous function?

Comment: `alert.bind(this, 'hello world')`

Comment: Try to avoid binding in rendering function, you could do this in constructor or outside the class declaration if no class "this" context is required.

Answer (score 5):

you should wrap the alert in a function you can use fat arrows to do the job

```
<a onClick={() => alert("hello world")} >hello</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should give `onClick` a function that it can call on the click event, so you should wrap the alert in an anonymous function, e.g.

```
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');

var Main = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                 <a onClick={function () {alert("hello world")}} >hello</a>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```